# service monitoring manager for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, monitoring, services

My mate told me that there's a tool to manage services in Ubuntu, *System > Administration > Services*.  But unfortunately, I don't found it in my Ubuntu (9.10) also in 10.04 .  Is it easy to get it?  or What package do I need to install?

If not, are there any alternative GUI programs to manage services (like mysql, apache and so forth)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to use GNOME Boot-Up Manager to manage services.